# ZURB Foundation, switching tab programmatically

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, zurb-foundation

Im using asp with foundation, is there anyway to switch between a tab to another using JS or ASP?

[Link](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/tabs.php) (Simple tab).

Comment: Do you mean switch tabs from the code behind? (server side)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A possible solution is to assign an id to the tab link and click it using jQuery.

Given the following code excerpt, notice the id assigned to the anchor link...

```
<dd><a href="#simple2" id="tabId">Simple Tab 2</a></dd>
```

You could activate this link using this line of jQuery.

```
$("#tabId").click();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you give the first tab and the first LI .active by default in the HTML,

```
<div id="#TheTabs" class="twelve columns">

    <dl class="nice contained tabs">
        <dd><a href="#FirstTab" class="active">First Tab</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#SecondTab">Second Tab</a></dd>
    </dl>

    <ul class="nice contained tabs-content">
        <li id="FirstTabLI" class="active">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="twelve columns">
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="SecondTabLI">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="twelve columns">
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Then you can change the tab in javascript,

```
if ( activeTab == 2 ) {

    // Clear tab 1
    $('#TheTabs dl dd a[href="#FirstTab"]').removeClass("active");
    $('#FirstTabLI').removeClass("active");

    // Select tab 2
    $('#TheTabs dl dd a[href="#SecondTab"]').addClass("active");
    $('#SecondTabLI').addClass("active");

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without adding an ID to each list item, and keeping the hash in the URL location.

Let's say you have this code:

```
  <div id="my-menu" class="menu">
    <ul class="vertical tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#overview">Overview</a></li>
      <li><a href="#feedback">Feedback</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Then you can do this anywhere on the page:

```
<a href="#feedback" onclick="$('#my-menu a[href=\'#feedback\']').click()">Feedback</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

In version 3.0 you can set a class of `active` on the tab `dl.tabs dd` and the `ul.tabs-content li` to switch them. You can do that in code or in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#yourTabsContainer').on('click', '.yourNextButton', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
});
```

and this previous button(if you need)

```
$('#yourTabsContainer').on('click', '.yourPreviousButton', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $('.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
});
```

It's working for me...

Answer (score 0):

In foundation v5 you can use toggle_active_tab function:

```js
var $secondTab = $('ul.tabs > li:nth-child(2)');

Foundation.libs.tab.toggle_active_tab($secondTab, 'optional_location_hash')
```